# Customize WooCommerce attribute table to two columns

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm looking for some help getting customize the attribute table on WooCommerce.

```
<table>
<?php foreach (array_chunk($product_attributes, 2) as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute) :{ ?>
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($product_attribute as $value) :{ ?>
           <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $value['label'] ); ?></th>
           <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $value['value'] ); ?></td>
    <?php } endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php } endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I tried modify  the above snippet in order to break line between Attribute Name and Attribute Value to display the attributes like it is in the below picture.

[attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJm0Q.png)

Is there any easy hook to get this work?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create child-theme in case of theme update to not lose your settings.

Create in child-theme folders /woocommerce/single-product/ and copy from woocommerce/templates/single-product the file  product-attributes.php.

Change:

```
  defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
  return;

}
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
  <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
      <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
          <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
          <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></td>
      </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

to

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! $product_attributes ) {
    return;
}
$i = 0;
?>

<div class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <div class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></div>
            <div class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php 
    if ($i % 2 != 0){
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
    $i++;
    endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

add CSS

```
/*2 Columnt style on product attributes*/
.woocommerce-product-attributes.shop_attributes .woocommerce-product-attributes-item {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
        padding-right:10px;
}
```